# Modify a Python "requests" module response object

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm requesting an HTTP API with the Python "requests" module.

```
result = requests.get(api_url)
```

The response is in JSON format and contains a 'data' key which is a dictionary.
For some reasons, I have to make a second request further in the script and I'm trying to update the first dictionary (`result.json['data']`) with the second (`result2.json['data']`).

I tried this:

```
result.json['data'].update(result2.json['data'])
```

and this:

```
for key,value in dict(result2.json['data']).iteritems():
    result.json['data'][key] = value
```

but none of these worked, the final `result.json['data']` is not modified and only contains the first items.

So I'm wondering if the Python "Requests" module produces some king of "read-only" objects or if I am just missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`result.json()` is either a *method* (requests 1.0 and up) or a *property*. Store the result of that method or property in a variable, then update that:

```
json_result = result.json()
# requests < 1.0: json_result = result.json

json_result['data'].update(result2.json()['data'])
```

(In older `requests` versions (pre-1.0), `result.json` is a *property*, and underneath that is still a method returning your object on the fly).

Otherwise, `Response` objects are not meant to be mutable. You'd have to alter the response *body text* to alter what `result.json` returns, and it would require intimate knowledge of how the `Response` objects cache the response body to alter that. This would tie you to a specific `requests` version.

For the *current* `requests` series (2.4.x), you can swap out the `response._content` attribute:

```
result.encoding, result._content = 'utf8', json.dumps(json_result)
```

where I've made the assumption that `result.content` already exists (e.g. a streaming response has already been consumed), and that `json_result` has already been updated.

If this will work in other `requests` versions depends; `_content` is an internal, private attribute. The leading underscore indicates it is not part of the public API, so the developers are free to change the meaning of that attribute or altogether remove it in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if I do this, my final object is no longer a "response" object, and this is a prerequisite for me.

Comment: @gr0bz: Why exactly is that? You'd have to convert the Python data structure back to a JSON string and update the `Response` object. Hardly a robust solution.